# Correct GCC compile command for building exe (to use with gdb)

Tags: gcc, compilation, gdb, flags

I have a file called `val_ref.c` and I compiled it using the command flag:

`gcc val_ref.c -DDEBUG`

after that, I opened gdb using the following command:

`gdb a` % the resulting execuatable is called a

Then I used the following commands to set breakpoints and run the debugger:

```
(gdb) break main
(gdb) break incvar
(gdb) run
(gdb) continue
```

However, I cannot see the line-by-line proceeding information on the console. Instead, I see this:

[image: Output of console]

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. For example, if I was to build this as a console application in VS2010 or Eclipse Kepler (with MinGW toolchain), and then run `gdb` on the exec, it will work perfect, (I think). Seems like I am not adding the correct directives/flags in my compile. Can anybody help me with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the -g flag? This the usual flag for gdb..

Answer (score 0):

The best flags to use to compile for debugging are -g and -O0. -g causes GCC to add debugging information to the executable, and -O0 stops GCC enabling optimizations which would be confusing when debugging.